# Query to get column names and values in result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with id as the first field an other fields with description fields. E.g.

```
id | color | length | year | land | name
---------------------------------------------------
3 | blue | long | 1988 | Netherlands | Jan
4 | yellow | short ..etc.
```

I would like to make a new table with on every row the following fields: id, fieldname (from my first table), value of that field. So like this:

```
3 | color | blue
3 | length | long
3 | year | 1988
3 | land | Netherlands
3 | name | Jan
4 | color | yellow
4 | length | short
etc.
```

Does anyone know how to do this in a query? (Or otherwise in a php-script?)

Thanks and kind regards, Ali

Comment: The number of columns is fixed and known in advance, right?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need compatible data types to do what you want.  That would normally be a string.

Then, you can do this in several ways.  Probably the simplest in MySQL is `union all`:

```
select id, 'color' as which, color from t union all
select id, 'length' as which, cast(length as char) from t union all
. . .
```